# Do you need to log a model using MLflow's PyTorch API before loading it?

Tags: mlflow

I'm currently trying to load a model's checkpoint directly using MLflow's PyTorch API. I have the checkpoint stored as an artifact and am trying to use the run ID to load it. However, when I try to run the following: `mlflow.pytorch.load(model(f"runs:/{run_id}/models/model_best.pth", dst_path="./", tracking_uri="https://mlflow.some_url.com")`, I get the following error:

```
MlflowException: Could not find an "MLmodel" configuration file at "/home/user/$dst_path/model_best.pth"
```

I took a look at the [Models documentation for MLflow](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html) but it doesn't seem 100% clear to me yet what the problem might be.

One thing that I'm suspecting is that maybe I need to save my PyTorch model using `mlflow.pytorch.log_model` first before loading it? Would appreciate any thoughts.